# Can't create Quality Profiles in sonarqube (JS error)

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube

Hi I am trying to create Quality Profiles but Create button doesn't work. I can errors in browser console

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at t.render (CreateProfileForm.tsx:105)
    at h._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:796)
    at h._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:819)
    at h.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:359)
    at h.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
    at Object.updateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:119)
    at g._reconcilerUpdateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:209)
    at g._updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:308)
    at g.updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:295)
```

I have tried with 6.7.3, 6.7.4. Not sure if this is an issue with my installation.

Answer (score 0):

OK something didn't go well in the first start when it creates default Quality Profiles. 'Create' button throws JS error when Quality Profiles are empty. This is still a bug but can be avoided if there is at least one Quality Profile defined.